# ScriptEngine how to pass a String that represent JSON?

Tags: json, rhino

I was trying to pass a String object that represents a JSON string from java to javascript function using ScriptEngine in jdk 1.6.

My code works in JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/hn4yk/13/ but when I try to load it with the ScriptEngine it doesn't work and throws an exception  sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "resultList" from undefined (#1164)

I tested that the variable is passed correctly but the eval or the JSON.parse method doesn't work! I tried to put the library for JSON.parse and my function in the same file!

This is my java code:

```
public class InvokeScriptMethod {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("C:/Subclipse/TestJavascriptServerSide/jsonInput.txt");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(stream, writer, "UTF-8");
        String jsonString = writer.toString();

        InputStream javascriptStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Subclipse/TestJavascriptServerSide/Script");
        StringWriter writerScript = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(javascriptStream, writerScript, "UTF-8");
        String javascriptString = writerScript.toString();

        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByExtension("js");

        engine.eval(javascriptString);

        Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;

        String convertedJson = (String)inv.invokeFunction("convertJSON",jsonString);

        System.out.println("results"+convertedJson);

        // now should I convert it to a writer to reply in a webapplication as response.getWriter().print(convertedJson);
        // and I would like to don't lose the JSON formatting to see data with indentation
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the jsonInput file I had to put all Json Stream in a single line and it works!